# adding a second outer query in a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query below that gives me median, I want to put my **count(*)** that counts the total # of rows that I use in my median calculation in a seperate subquery (since it runs a bit better that way). What is the best way to do that? Thank you!

```
 SELECT our_id, AVG(1.0 * our_val) as Median
FROM
( SELECT our_id, our_val, 
  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY our_id) AS cnt,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY our_id ORDER BY our_val) AS rn
  FROM our_table
) AS x
WHERE rn IN ((cnt + 1)/2, (cnt + 2)/2) GROUP BY our_id;
```

Comment: Please show the value that you want.

Comment: I dont want a diff value just wanted to know how to keep same output but instead move the count(*) to a different subquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calculating `count(*)` in the subquery.  Why not just use that?

```
SELECT our_id, AVG(1.0 * our_val) as Median, cnt
FROM (SELECT our_id, our_val, 
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY our_id) AS cnt,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY our_id ORDER BY our_val) AS rn
      FROM our_table
     ) x
WHERE rn IN ((cnt + 1)/2, (cnt + 2)/2)
GROUP BY our_id, cnt;
```

Comment: No I meant I don't want a difference in my output, I was told to tweak this query to where count(*) is in a separate subquery so it will run better? thnx

Comment: or do you think that is not needed? and this is good as i have it? thnx

Comment: @Chris90 . . . I doubt you will notice the difference in performance by including this information in this query.

Comment: I dont want to inclue cnt in the query output, I was told to move the count*) to another subquery? or is that not needed?

Comment: how you have it is optimal, if count in a separate subquery you will be forcing two scans of the table instead of 1, why would you want that?

Comment: Thanks! just was confused if it was or not thanks!